# jQuery Slow Style Update

Tags: jquery, resize, window

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my resize events to sync. Basically, $M.resize updates a div's width (css) and then I want $API.resize to read that new size and update its elements accordingly. However, if I set the window resize event (see below) and then immediately trigger the window's resize event, $API.resize doesn't get any new width information - almost as if $M.resize hasn't finished updating. $API.resize gets the new width information via $("#main").css("width"); The only way I can get it to work is by the workaround below using setTimeout.. is there a better way to do this?

```
// on page load
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $M.resize();
        $API.resize();
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(window).resize();
    }, 100);
});

// $API.resize
function () {
    var pageWidth = $M.width();
    console.log("pageWidth = " + pageWidth);
    $("#atmoGrid").css("width", pageWidth);
    $(".atmoSector")
        .css("width", pageWidth/5-2)
        .css("height", pageWidth/5-2);
}

// $M.resize
function () {
    // refresh screen dimensions
    width = Math.min(screen.availWidth, window.innerWidth);
    height = Math.min(screen.availHeight, window.innerHeight);
    smallScreen = (width < smallWidth);
    fontScale = (smallScreen) ? 3 : 1;

    // check if screen is small
    if (smallScreen) {
        $("#main").css("width", "100%");
    } else {
        $("#main").css("width", smallWidth + "px")
    }
    $("#main").css("font-size", $M.font(18));
}

// $M.width
function () {
    var width = $("#main").css("width");
    return parseInt(width);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to show us some more of your code, right now it's just some variables and triggering of the resize event, where's the functions that set the CSS etc. ?

Comment: $API.resize(); will not pick up any changes from $M.resize();, as it is out of scope. Use some Global variables

Comment: k I added the function bodies for $M.resize and $API.resize as well as a few others. I should note that $M and $API are both global.

Comment: maybe implement some callback in $M.resize(), to fire when it has finished updating, and you'd have something like $M.resize($API.resize)?

Comment: maybe call API from the last line of $M.Resize with two parameters being the width and height of the elements that you need?

Comment: I still don't get it, how are you calling those functions? Right now you're just triggering a resize event on those variables, and natively only the window object has a resize event, not elements, all though you can always set up custom events like resize, or create your own function called resize, which would cause a conflict with jQuery's resize() function ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// on page load
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $M.resize();
    });
});

// $API.resize
function (mWidth, mHeight) {
    var pageWidth = mWidth;
    console.log("pageWidth = " + pageWidth);
    $("#atmoGrid").css("width", pageWidth);
    $(".atmoSector")
        .css("width", pageWidth/5-2)
        .css("height", pageWidth/5-2);
}

// $M.resize
function () {
    // refresh screen dimensions
    width = Math.min(screen.availWidth, window.innerWidth);
    height = Math.min(screen.availHeight, window.innerHeight);
    smallScreen = (width < smallWidth);
    fontScale = (smallScreen) ? 3 : 1;

    // check if screen is small
    if (smallScreen) {
        $("#main").css("width", "100%");
    } else {
        $("#main").css("width", smallWidth + "px")
    }
    $("#main").css("font-size", $M.font(18));

    $API.Resize(smallWidth, someheight);
}

// $M.width
function () {
    var width = $("#main").css("width");
    return parseInt(width);
}
```

hth